# How to make desktop color by xfconf-query in ubuntu18.04 please?

Tags: colors, desktop, xubuntu

My environment is xubuntu 18.04 64-bit. I use this to set desktop's color:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/workspace0/color1 -n -t int -t int -t int -t int -s 19018 -s 37008 -s 55769 -s 65535
```

Then I see the color is black. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works replacing type int for uint.

Answer (score 1):

With :

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/workspace0/color1
```

You get :

```
Value is an array with 4 items:

7936
16128
28416
65535
```

So you must set a array with -a option
For each item, you must specify first the type and after the value.
You can try this way :

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/workspace0/color1 -a -t int -s 19018 -t int -s 37008 -t int -s 55769 -t int -s 65535
```

Comment: Thank you. I try the last line but the color of desktop is still black. In my memory, my way can work good in xubuntu 14.04, but when 16.04, it can not work, and 18.04 too.